# Mongodb Mongoose sort and paginate chat messages

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, pagination, chat

I am making a chat app where 10 messages are loaded per page. The messages are sorted from oldest to latest, so the new messages come in bottom and old messages are in top. I tried to use skip() and limit() methods it didnt work.

```js
let count = page*10

MessageModel.find(find_query).sort({createdAt: 'asc'}).skip(count-10).limit(10).exec();
```

for example:

let these be my messages sorted oldest to newest: `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]`

the above query returns the data like this in
1st page: `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]`

2nd page : `["11", "12"]`

but I want it to return

in 1st page: `["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]`

in 2nd page: `["1", "2"]`

**EDIT:**
I tried sorting it into descending and reversing, this seemed to fix the issue.

```js
let count = page*10

const messages = await MessageModel.find(find_query).sort({createdAt: 'desc'}).skip(count-10).limit(10).exec();

const re_messages = messages.reverse()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you sort by 'desc' instead of 'asc'? This way, you would get the 10 newest messages (12 to 3). Then all you have to do is to invert them, to get 3 to 12

Comment: @JeremyThille yes i tried and it worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to display messages 3 to 12 first, you need to sort using 'desc' instead of 'asc', so as to get the newest messages first. This will give you `["12", "11", ... "4", "3"]`. Now all you have to do is to invert this array to get `["3", "4", ... "11", "12"]`:

```
let count = page*10

let messages = await MessageModel
                        .find(find_query)
                        .sort({createdAt: 'desc'}) // get the latest ones
                        .skip(count-10)
                        .limit(10)
                        .exec()
                        .lean(); // Get a simple array

messages.reverse(); // ["3", "4", ... "11", "12"]
```